# How do I get the current VRM temps on my HD5850?

Tags: cooling, temperature

Thinking about adding an aftermarket cooler to my ATI HD5850. I want an accurate picture of my current temps before and after so I don't break anything. I've seen on some forums that VRM temperatures are an issue with some after market coolers.

What software will give me readouts of these temperatures?

Comment: What's a VRM? (in 15 chars)

Comment: The video ram chips, as far as I understand it. You can buy dedicated cooling solutions for them. For example, Thermalright's VRM-R3

Comment: I believe VRMs are voltage regulators

Answer (score 1):

a VRM is a voltage regulator... not RAM.

I haven't found a way to check these temps with software personally but you could check with a probe or laser thermometer... though the latter would be pretty expensive!

Any aftermarket cooler will be better as long as you use a heatsink on the VRM. Stock they only come with a cheap thermal pad on them.

Check core temps with a tool like afterburner.